# GetCurrentLocation working in debug but not working in release apk in Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, plugins, geolocation

i have problem with geolocator package, when i run my app in debug mode everything works well but when i build the app and use the release mode it stuck in my loading screen which have the getcurrentlocation from geolocator package.

```
Future<void> getCurrentLocation() async {
    try {
      Geolocator geolocator = Geolocator()..forceAndroidLocationManager = true;
      Position position = await geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low,
      );
      latitude = position.latitude;
      longitude = position.longitude;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

and also add to android manifest access.

Comment: did you add release key to firebase console?

Comment: i m not using the firebase, i m using only geolocator plugin from flutter packages

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem with the Geolocator package, many of my users could not access their location and nor was the permission asked.

The solution was to use the [**location package**](https://pub.dev/packages/location#-readme-tab-) instead.

I cannot site the exact reason why this worked for me but it i have an app in production, and changing my package to this helped me.

Comment: i used now this package, same issue works well on debug mode and nothing in release mode
ps: when app starts it demands permission but keep loading location and nothing happen

Answer (score 1):

for my case i found that i must add internet permission into  AndroidManifest. xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```